# Time zone conversion C API on Linux, anyone?

Tags: c, linux, timezone

I'm looking for something that I presumed would be very simple - given local Unix time in a specific time zone (specified as a string, e.g., "America/New_York" - note that's *not* my local time), get the corresponding time value in GMT. I.e., something along the lines of

```
time_t get_gmt_time(time_t local_time,
                    const char* time_zone);
```

As deceptively simple as it sounds, the closest I could find was the following code snippet from timegm's man page:

```
       #include <time.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       time_t
       my_timegm(struct tm *tm)
       {
           time_t ret;
           char *tz;

           tz = getenv("TZ");
           setenv("TZ", "", 1);
           tzset();
           ret = mktime(tm);
           if (tz)
               setenv("TZ", tz, 1);
           else
               unsetenv("TZ");
           tzset();
           return ret;
       }
```

There gotta be a better way than this belligerently not thread-safe abomination, right? Right??

Comment: Good question.  Things are really nearly that bad.  All the world seems to think you'd never be interested in pretending to be in a different time zone, or need to convert to any time zone other than, perhaps, UTC.  It is a problem.

Comment: There's a slight confusion here as to what `time_t` and `struct tm` mean. On all UN*X-like systems, `time_t` / `time()` is "seconds since 'epoch'` (UTC 0:00 01/01/1970), which can be converted to a `struct tm` via either `localtime()` (giving a timezone-corrected result) or `gmtime()` (giving a result in UTC), resp. their reentrant versions. `mktime()` is the opposite, converts `struct tm` into `time_t`.  
What you've coded therefore is just `mktime()` in disguise ?

Comment: I too am interested in the thread-safety question.  How to convert to/from an arbitrary timezone, not necessarily the "current" zone, in a **thread-safe**  way.  Not just conversion, but also using strftime to print out the zone.

Comment: It's 2015 and i'm still searching for a thread-safe solution

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to add a bit more detail here.

If you try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>    /* defines 'extern long timezone' */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_t t, lt, gt;
    struct tm tm;

    t = time(NULL);
    lt = mktime(localtime(&t));
    gt = mktime(gmtime(&t));

    printf( "(t = time(NULL)) == %x,\n"
        "mktime(localtime(&t)) == %x,\n"
        "mktime(gmtime(&t)) == %x\n"
        "difftime(...) == %f\n"
        "timezone == %d\n", t, lt, gt,
        difftime(gt, lt), timezone);
    return 0;
}
```

you'll notice that timezone conversions make sure that:

- `mktime(localtime(t)) == t`, and
- `mktime(gmtime(t)) == t + timezone`,
  therefore:
- `difftime(mktime(gmtime(t)), mktime(localtime(t))) == timezone`
  (the latter is a global variable initialized by either `tzset()` or the invocation of any timezone conversion function).

Example output of the above:

```
$ TZ=GMT ./xx
(t = time(NULL)) == 4dd13bac,
mktime(localtime(&t)) == 4dd13bac,
mktime(gmtime(&t)) == 4dd13bac
difftime(...) == 0.000000
timezone == 0

$ TZ=EST ./xx
(t = time(NULL)) == 4dd13baf,
mktime(localtime(&t)) == 4dd13baf,
mktime(gmtime(&t)) == 4dd181ff
difftime(...) == 18000.000000
timezone == 18000

$ TZ=CET ./xx
(t = time(NULL)) == 4dd13bb2,
mktime(localtime(&t)) == 4dd13bb2,
mktime(gmtime(&t)) == 4dd12da2
difftime(...) == -3600.000000
timezone == -3600
```

In that sense, you're attempting to "do it backwards" - `time_t` is treated as *absolute* in UN*X, i.e. always relative to the "EPOCH" (0:00 UTC on 01/01/1970).

The difference between UTC and the current timezone (last `tzset()` call) is always in the `external long timezone` global.

That doesn't get rid of the environment manipulation uglyness, but you can save yourself the effort of going through `mktime()`.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, because offset between timezones is not constant (think DST and historical offset changes).

Comment: Please clarify - what _exactly_ would you "not do" ? I agree the UN*X timezone mechanism isn't supposed to be a historical database. Nonetheless, can you give an example where the above gives incorrect output ?

Comment: This answer actually is the best!  Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

From tzfile(5), which documents the files in /usr/share/zoneinfo (on my system) in gruesome detail:

> It seems that  timezone  uses tzfile
>   internally, but glibc refuses to
>   expose it to userspace.  This is most
>   likely because the standardised
>   functions are more useful and
>   portable, and actually documented by
>   glibc.

Again, this is probably not what you're looking for (ie. an API), but the information is there and you can parse it without too much pain.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like about the only way to make this work, as ugly as it is. Of course, once implemented, I'll end up with a generic timezone conversion API I was looking for in the first place :o

As I'm currently dealing with a single-threaded forked process, I may not have enough motivation to do this and will likely just opt for the TZ "hack" mentioned in timegm's man page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with gmtime, localtime and their variants is the reliance on the TZ environment variable. The time functions first call tzset(void), which reads TZ to determine offsets DST, etc. If TZ is not set in the user's environment, (g)libc uses the system timezone. So if you have a local struct tm in, say, 'Europe/Paris' and your machine  or environment is set to 'America/Denver', the wrong offset will be applied when you convert to GMT. All the time functions call tzset(void) which reads TZ to set char *tzname[2], long timezone (diff, in seconds, from GMT) and int daylight (boolean for DST). Setting these directly has no affect, because tzset() will overwrite them the next time you call localtime, etc.

I was faced with the same issue as 'igor' in the original question, while setenv works it seems problematic (re-entran?). I decided to look further to see if I could modify tzset (void) to tzset(char*) to explicitly set the above mentioned variables. Well, of course, that's just a bad idea... but in probing the glibc source and the IANA TZ database source, I came to the conclusion that the setenv approach ain't so bad.

First, setenv only modifies the process global 'char **environ' (not the calling shell, so the 'real' TZ is not affected). And, second, glibc actually puts a lock in setenv. The drawback is  that setenv/tzset calls are not atomic, so another thread could conceivably write to TZ before the original thread call tzset. But a well-implemented application that uses threads should watch for that anyway.

It would be cool if POSIX defined tzset to take a char* for look up in the extensive IANA TZ database (and take NULL to mean, 'use the user or system TZ/), but failing that, setenv seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I really thought there was something in glib, but seem to have misremembered. I know you're probably looking for straight-up C code, but here's the best I've got:

I know that Python has some notion of timezones through a `tzinfo` class - you can read about it in the [datetime documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime). You can have a look at the source code for the module (in the [tarball](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/Python-2.6.2.tgz), it's in Modules/datetime.c) - it appears to have some documentation, so maybe you can get something out of it.

Comment: Yes, I meant straight C API of course - subject's corrected now, thanks!

As for looking at the Python implementation, that idea crossed my mind but I really hoped to avoid going that path. Having looked at the source and then the API docs, I found that Python's datetime is blissfully unaware of time zones - all it gives is you is an abstract tzinfo class that you're supposed to implement if you're to do time conversions between time zones. There are a few libraries that implement that but, really - are things really *that* bad?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the Python answer, I can show you what [**R**](http://www.r-project.org) does:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()       # get current time
R> format(now)             # format under local TZ
[1] "2009-08-03 18:55:57"
R> format(now,tz="Europe/London")   # format under explicit TZ
[1] "2009-08-04 00:55:57"
R> format(now,tz="America/Chicago") # format under explicit TZ
[1] "2009-08-03 18:55:57"
R>
```

but R uses an internal representation that extends the usual `struct tm` --- see R-2.9.1/src/main/datetime.c.

Still, this is a hairy topic and it would be nice if it were the standard library. As it isn't maybe your best bet is to use [Boost Date_Time (example)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion)

Comment: From what I understand, Boost's Date_time doesn't make use of system's zoneinfo files and relies on its own timezone database instead - which makes it a non-starter, IMHO. Do correct me if I got it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the `gmtime_r()`?  Following worked fine for me:

```
int main()
{
    time_t t_gmt, t_local=time(NULL);
    struct tm tm_gmt;

    gmtime_r(&t_local, &tm_gmt);

    t_gmt = mktime(&tm_gmt);

    printf("Time now is:    %s", ctime(&t_local));
    printf("Time in GMT is: %s", ctime(&t_gmt));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have been wondering the same, particularly since the orig poster said "GMT".

Comment: That's pretty nice, but imagine that the computer time zone is +1 and the time you want to convert is +2. And that's not the worst case scenario. Imagine that computer time zone is Europe/Amsterdam as in my case and the time you want to convert in `tm` structure is in Europe/Athens timezone. It's not only adding/substracting one hour, but also daylight saving time which is different around the globe.