# Get local time from UTC time

Tags: c++, datetime, utc, epoch

I have an epoc time **1432743742** that represents **Wed, 27 May 2015 16:22:22**

(See http://www.epochconverter.com/)

This time is actually **27/05/2015, 17:22:22 GMT+1:00 DST**

In C++ how can I get the GMT+1:00 time when I know the epoc time and the time zone e.g. **"GMT Standard Time"**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time zone conversion C API on Linux, anyone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223947/time-zone-conversion-c-api-on-linux-anyone)

Comment: Forgot to say I'm on Windows.

Comment: this is standard c runtime should be applicable.  But if you want windows-specific, I seem to remember that Windows-specific APIs where not particularly helpful in that regard.

Comment: Are you asking how to render a human-readable date and time string in a known timezone? Or what?

Comment: No I'm not asking how to make it human readable. I need to know how to convert the original UTC time to take the timezone into consideration and get the time in that timezone.

Comment: So I start off with the epoc time of 1432743742 which represents 27/05/2015, 16:22:22 but I know that my timezone is GMT Standard Time so I need to get an output of 27/05/2015, 17:22:22 (Note the time is now 17 instead of 16)

Comment: If the value is still a number - that should *always* be in UTC.  It's only when you get a human readable string that you would adjust it for time zone.

Comment: Trust me I need to convert the time to take the timezone into consideration.