# C++: converting Unix time to non-local timezone

Tags: c++, time, timezone, posix

I am trying to convert a time held in a variable of `time_t` to a `struct tm*` in some time zone which is not the local time zone.

Building on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223947/time-zone-conversion-c-api-on-linux-anyone), which discusses the inverse operation going from `struct tm*` to `time_t`, I have written the following function:

```
struct tm* localtime_tz(time_t* t, std::string timezone) {

  struct tm* ret;
  char* tz;

  tz = std::getenv("TZ"); // Store currently set time zone                                                                                                                           

  // Set time zone                                                                                                                                                                   
  setenv("TZ", timezone.c_str(), 1);
  tzset();

  std::cout << "Time zone set to " << std::getenv("TZ") << std::endl;

  ret = std::localtime(t); // Convert given Unix time to local time in time zone                                                                                                     
  std::cout << "Local time is: " << std::asctime(ret);
  std::cout << "UTC time is: " << std::asctime(std::gmtime(t));

  // Reset time zone to stored value                                                                                                                                                 
  if (tz)
    setenv("TZ", tz, 1);
  else
    unsetenv("TZ");
  tzset();

  return ret;

}
```

However, the conversion fails, and I get

```
Time zone set to CEST
Local time is: Wed Aug  9 16:39:38 2017
UTC time is: Wed Aug  9 16:39:38 2017
```

i.e. local time is set to UTC time, instead of UTC+2 for CEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone abbreviations shown by `date` and other tools are not the names of time zones.  The IANA time zone database uses a major city within the relevant region instead.  The reason for that is that the abbreviations are not unique, and they do not convey sufficient information to convert past dates because places switch time zones.

In addition, POSIX specifies that the `TZ` variable has to be parsed in a specific way, and it pretty much suggests to treat a bare time zone abbreviation like UTC (but with a different abbreviation).

Instead, you have to use the actual time zone name, such as `Europe/Berlin`, or a POSIX time zone specifier such as `CET-1CEST`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing an additional answer in case someone wants to do this in a way that is thread safe (without setting a global such as an environment variable).  This answer requires C++11 (or better) and [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), which has been ported to linux, macOS and Windows.

This library builds on `<chrono>`, extending it to calendars and timezones.  One can interface with the C timing API such as `struct tm` with this library, but such facilities aren't built in to the library.  This library makes the C API unnecessary, unless you have to interface with other code that uses the C API.

For example there is a type called `date::zoned_seconds` that couples a `system_clock::time_point` (except with `seconds` precision) with a `date::time_zone` to create local time in an arbitrary time zone.  As [described in more detail here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#Ccompatiblity), here is how you can convert a `zoned_seconds` into a `std::tm`:

```
std::tm
to_tm(date::zoned_seconds tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto lt = tp.get_local_time();
    auto ld = floor<days>(lt);
    time_of_day<seconds> tod{lt - ld};  // <seconds> can be omitted in C++17
    year_month_day ymd{ld};
    tm t{};
    t.tm_sec  = tod.seconds().count();
    t.tm_min  = tod.minutes().count();
    t.tm_hour = tod.hours().count();
    t.tm_mday = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    t.tm_mon  = unsigned{ymd.month()} - 1;
    t.tm_year = int{ymd.year()} - 1900;
    t.tm_wday = unsigned{weekday{ld}};
    t.tm_yday = (ld - local_days{ymd.year()/jan/1}).count();
    t.tm_isdst = tp.get_info().save != minutes{0};
    return t;
}
```

Using this building block, it becomes almost trivial to convert a `time_t` to a `tm` in an arbitrary time zone (without setting a global):

```
std::tm
localtime_tz(time_t t, const std::string& timezone)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return to_tm({timezone, floor<seconds>(system_clock::from_time_t(t))});
}
```

If you're using C++17, you can remove `using namespace date` as `floor<seconds>` will be completely provided within `namespace std::chrono`.

The above code creates a `zoned_seconds` from the `string` `timezone` and a `system_clock::time_point` derived from the `time_t` `t`.  The `zoned_seconds` is conceptually a `pair<time_zone, system_clock::time_point>` but of arbitrary precision.  And it can also be thought of as a `pair<time_zone, local_time>` since the `time_zone` knows how to map between UTC and local time.  So most of the user-written code above is just in extracting the local time from the `zoned_seconds` and placing that into a `struct tm`.

The above code can be exercised like this:

```
auto tm = localtime_tz(time(nullptr), "America/Anchorage");
```

If you don't need the result in a `tm` but can instead stay within the `<chrono>` system, there exists very nice features in the [timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) for parsing and formatting the `zoned_seconds`, for example:

```
cout << zoned_seconds{"America/Anchorage", floor<seconds>(system_clock::now())} << '\n';
```

Sample output:

```
2017-08-10 16:50:28 AKDT
```